# Return JSON from Django template

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates

I already looked at a few existing answers for this question but could not solve my problem.

I have a python dictionary in one of my views. I convert it to json using json.dumps() and then send this to a template.

The template returns the JSON properly if all of the JSON values have no spaces. But if a key has a value which is separated by a whitespace, the JSON string returned by the template is truncated after the whitespace.

An Android SDK reads the returned JSON string and if any key has whitespace separated values that's how I know  the returned JSON string is truncated.

**views.py:**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def temp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    response_dict = {}
        response_dict['KEY1'] = 'hello'
        response_dict['KEY2'] = 'hello world'
        param_dict = json.dumps(response_dict, separators=(',', ':'))
        return render(request, 'validate.html', {'params_dict': param_dict})
```

**validate.html**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-I">
<title>HELLO</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function response(){
        return document.getElementById('response').value;
    }       
</script>
</head>
Redirect back to the app<br>
<form name="frm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="response" name="responseField" value={{ params_dict }}>
</form>
```

As seen above in the views, if KEY2 has the value "hello world" without spaces, i.e. "helloworld", the JSON string ss returned properly by the template, or else it is truncated after "hello"

Comment: Why don't you just check the output with Postman or Curl instead to make sure it's not something that the Android SDK does?

Comment: So when I display the JSON string in HTML using {{ params_dict }} it shows up fine. But how do i see the output of theJavaScript portion: function response(){
        return document.getElementById('response').value;
    }.  How do i know if the JSON is rendered properly or not?

Comment: All you are doing there is reading the value of the input field. Your problem is most likely on the Android side. Download Postman and do a POST call to your server to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the value in quotes in the template:

```
<input type="hidden" id="response" name="responseField" value="{{ params_dict }}">
```